# Merge CSV files into a single file with no repeated headers

Tags: java, csv

I have some CSV files with the same column headers. For example

File A

```
header1,header2,header3
one,two,three
four,five,six
```

File B

```
header1,header2,header3
seven,eight,nine
ten,eleven,twelve
```

I want to merge it so that the data is merged into one file with the headers at the top, but no headers anywhere else.

```
header1,header2,header3
one,two,three
four,five,six
seven,eight,nine
ten,eleven,twelve
```

What is a good way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm assuming you would know how to read files line by line. When you write back the lines to a file, skip the first line in each successive file after the first one.

Comment: Either create a text file that just contains the header and append each CSV to that while skipping the first line, or read all of them, not skipping the first line of the first file. The first would be a bit easier, and the second would be relatively easy and more portable if you had different sets of files with different headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. It checks if the file being merged have matching headers. Would throw an exception otherwise. Exception handling (to close the streams etc.) has been left as an exercise.

```
String[] headers = null;
String firstFile = "/path/to/firstFile.dat";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(firstFile));

if (scanner.hasNextLine())
    headers[] = scanner.nextLine().split(",");

scanner.close();

Iterator<File> iterFiles = listOfFilesToBeMerged.iterator();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(firstFile, true));

while (iterFiles.hasNext()) {
  File nextFile = iterFiles.next();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nextFile));

  String line = null;
  String[] firstLine = null;
  if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    firstLine = line.split(",");

  if (!Arrays.equals (headers, firstLine))
    throw new FileMergeException("Header mis-match between CSV files: '" +
              firstFile + "' and '" + nextFile.getAbsolutePath());

  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(line);
    writer.newLine();
  }

  reader.close();
}
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Path> paths = Arrays.asList(Paths.get("c:/temp/file1.csv"), Paths.get("c:/temp/file2.csv"));
    List<String> mergedLines = getMergedLines(paths);
    Path target = Paths.get("c:/temp/merged.csv");
    Files.write(target, mergedLines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}

private static List<String> getMergedLines(List<Path> paths) throws IOException {
    List<String> mergedLines = new ArrayList<> ();
    for (Path p : paths){
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(p, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        if (!lines.isEmpty()) {
            if (mergedLines.isEmpty()) {
                mergedLines.add(lines.get(0)); //add header only once
            }
            mergedLines.addAll(lines.subList(1, lines.size()));
        }
    }
    return mergedLines;
}
```

Comment: What is Paths, what jar file is htis ?

Comment: it's part of the standard JDK since Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html

Comment: if there exist merged.csv already. This would overwrite the existing file?

Comment: It's in [the javadoc of Files.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-): "*The options parameter specifies how the the file is created or opened. If no options are present then this method works as if the CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE options are present.*"

Answer (score 3):

It seems a bit heavyweight to do this in Java. Its trivial in a Linux shell:

```
(cat FileA ; tail --lines=+2 FileB) > FileC
```

Answer (score 2):

Late here but Fuzzy-Csv (https://github.com/kayr/fuzzy-csv/) was designed just for that.

This is what the code would look like

```
        String csv1 = "NAME,SURNAME,AGE\n" +
                "Fred,Krueger,Unknown";

        String csv2 = "NAME,MIDDLENAME,SURNAME,AGE\n" +
                "Jason,Noname,Scarry,16";

        FuzzyCSVTable t1 = FuzzyCSVTable.parseCsv(csv1);
        FuzzyCSVTable t2 = FuzzyCSVTable.parseCsv(csv2);

        FuzzyCSVTable output = t1.mergeByColumn(t2);

        output.printTable();
```

Output

```
╔═══════╤═════════╤═════════╤════════════╗
║ NAME  │ SURNAME │ AGE     │ MIDDLENAME ║
╠═══════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║ Fred  │ Krueger │ Unknown │ -          ║
╟───────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────────╢
║ Jason │ Scarry  │ 16      │ Noname     ║
╚═══════╧═════════╧═════════╧════════════╝
```

You can re-export your csv using one of the helper methods

```
output.write("FilePath.csv");

or 

output.toCsvString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before:

> idFile#x_y.csv

After:

> idFile.csv

For example:

> 100#1_2.csv + 100#2_2.csv > 100.csv

100#1_2.csv contains:

```
"one","two","three"
"a","b","c"
"d","e","f"
```

100#2_2.csv contains:

```
"one","two","three"
"g","h","i"
"j","k","l"
```

100.csv contains:

```
"one","two","three"
"a","b","c"
"d","e","f"    
"g","h","i"
"j","k","l"
```

Source:

```
//MergeDemo.java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MergeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String idFile = "100";
        int numFiles = 3;

        try {
            mergeCsvFiles(idFile, numFiles);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void mergeCsvFiles(String idFile, int numFiles) throws IOException {

        // Variables
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        Iterator<File> iterFiles;
        File fileOutput;
        BufferedWriter fileWriter;
        BufferedReader fileReader;
        String csvFile;
        String csvFinal = "C:\\out\\" + idFile + ".csv";
        String[] headers = null;
        String header = null;

        // Files: Input
        for (int i = 1; i <= numFiles; i++) {
            csvFile = "C:\\in\\" + idFile + "#" + i + "_" + numFiles + ".csv";
            files.add(new File(csvFile));
        }

        // Files: Output
        fileOutput = new File(csvFinal);
        if (fileOutput.exists()) {
            fileOutput.delete();
        }
        try {
            fileOutput.createNewFile();
            // log
            // System.out.println("Output: " + fileOutput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // log
        }

        iterFiles = files.iterator();
        fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFinal, true));

        // Headers
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(files.get(0));
        if (scanner.hasNextLine())
            header = scanner.nextLine();
        // if (scanner.hasNextLine()) headers = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
        scanner.close();

        /*
         * System.out.println(header); for(String s: headers){
         * fileWriter.write(s); System.out.println(s); }
         */

        fileWriter.write(header);
        fileWriter.newLine();

        while (iterFiles.hasNext()) {

            String line;// = null;
            String[] firstLine;// = null;

            File nextFile = iterFiles.next();
            fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nextFile));

            if ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
                firstLine = line.split(";");

            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                fileWriter.write(line);
                fileWriter.newLine();
            }
            fileReader.close();
        }

        fileWriter.close();

    }

}
```