# Merge Multiple csv files into Single csv using Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a business case of Merge Multiple csv files(around 1000+ Each containing 1000 records )into Single csv using Spring batch .

Please help me provide your guidance and solutions in terms of approach and performance-wise as well.

So far, I have tried two approaches,

**Approach 1.**

Tasklet chunk with multiResourceItemReader to read the files from directory and 
FlatFileItemWriter as item writer.

Issue here is, it is **very slow in processing** since this is single threaded, but approach works as expected.

**Approach 2:** 
    Using MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner and AsynTaskExceutor as task-executor.

Issue here is, since it is async multi-thread, **data is getting overwritten/ corrupted** while merging into final single file.

Comment: You need to show as what you have tried so far or according to you what you think can be a better approach as per your knowledge of Spring Batch framework? This will help to get better answers.

Comment: updated with solutions tried from my side. @SabirKhan

Comment: Are you doing any processing on source csv records ( like filtering etc ) or is it a simpl file merge with all headers being common ?

Comment: @SabirKhan - No filtering, it is simple files merge into one file with all common headers

Comment: Since there is no filtering/processing and all files have the same structure, then Approach 1 should be ok (even if single threaded). What do you mean by slow, can you give some numbers? Have you tried different values for the commit-interval? That said, do you really need Spring Batch for such a simple task? Something like `cat *.csv >> all.csv` or equivalent should do the trick (and should be faster).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `FlatFileItemWriter`  in `AsyncItemWriter` and use along with AsyncItemProcessor. This will not corrupt your data and increase the performance as processing and writing will be through several threads.

```java
@Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter asyncItemWriter() throws Exception {
        AsyncItemWriter<Customer> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();

        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(flatFileItemWriter);
        asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

        return asyncItemWriter;
    }

@Bean
    public AsyncItemProcessor asyncItemProcessor() throws Exception {
        AsyncItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor();

        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(itemProcessor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
        asyncItemProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();

        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }

@Bean
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("default_task_executor_thread");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @taushif for the solution.Time taken is 32 min

Answer (score 0):

Since your headers are common between your source and destination files, I wouldn't recommend using Spring Batch provided readers to convert lines into specific beans since column level information is not needed & csv being a text format , you can go ahead only with line level info without breaking it at field level.

Also, partitioning per file is going to be a very slow ( if you have those many files ) & you should try by first fixing your number of partitions ( like 10 or 20 ) and try grouping your files into those many partitions. Secondly file writing being a disk based operation & not CPU based, multi threading won't be useful.

What I suggest instead is to write your custom reader & writer in plain Java on the lines as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020643/3850730) where your reader will return a `List<String>` and writer will get `List<List<String>>` & that you can write to file.

If you have enough memory to hold lines from all files in one go then you can read all files in one go & keep returning **chunk_size** or you can keep reading small set of files to reach chunk size limit should be good enough. Your reader will return `null` when no more files to read.

Comment: Thanks @Sabir Khan for the solution and idea. I have also thought of same using JAVA 8 stream features. Wherein I have got huge time achievement by merge 35 files into 1 big file havings 350, 000 lines just in 5 min(Plain Java 8)  from 32 min(Spring batch approach).